# nginx fail SSL after upgrade ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04

Tags: nginx, ssl, ubuntu-22.04

I wonder if someone has encountered this issue with nginx after upgrade ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.

In nginx log file this appears. Seems to be something wrong with SSL.

2023/03/01 08:42:31 [emerg] 600#600: cannot load certificate key "/home/lars/ssl/_.(domain).se.key": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: error:1E08010C:DECODER routine
s::unsupported:No supported data to decode. Input type: PEM)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SLL certificate refused to work with the new version of nginx. creating a new solved the problem.